# Error with Function getting the correct Element ID from loop usingJavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a functional wages table using html and javascript that calculates the wage for each employee, according to input of each row.

To do this I have generated a different id for the total cell in each row of the table using a loop. The problem is that when i try to access each id in the loop that creates the table, the javascript function uses the last id name of the table created, instead of using the current id from the row that the function is called.
How can i get the correct id using only javascript and html?

```
This is my html code:
@foreach (var item in Model.CurrentUnpaidWages)
{
<tr>
    @{ id = Convert.ToString(Model.Employees[i].PersonID);}

    <td>
        @Model.Employees[i].FirstName   @Model.Employees[i].LastName
    </td>
    <td id="WagePerHour">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WagePerHour)
        @{wagePerHour = Convert.ToDecimal(item.WagePerHour);}
    </td>
    <td>
        @{ id = Convert.ToString(Model.Employees[i].PersonID);}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input oninput="GetWagePerMonth(this)" id=@id type="number" 
                     min="1" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wage.HoursPerMonth, 
                 "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><div id="d"@id></div></td>



    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bonus)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paid)</td>
    @{i++;}

    <td></td>

</tr>
```

This is my function:

```
function GetWagePerMonth(idx) {

    var h =idx.id;
    alert( "d" + idx.id);
    var wage = document.getElementById("WagePerHour").innerHTML;
    var wagePerHour = @wagePerHour;
    var wagePerMonth = wage * wagePerHour;
   wagePerMonth = round(wagePerMonth, 2).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("d" + idx.id).innerHTML = wagePerMonth;

 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: I've edited my code. See above.
Now I'm getting the correct id each time in an alert, but the function is not changing the text of the div id=@id. The div is staying empty. I would like that for each time I enter an amount into the input of :
  
then the correct text should be entered into the  div id=@id according to the function. For now, nothing is happening.

Comment: Since the element with id `WagePerHour` is not an `input`, using `.value` won't work, `.innerHTML` will. Furthermore, to make calculations the variables needs to be numbers, so something like this is needed: `Number(wage) * Number(wagePerHour)`

Comment: sorry, posted now edited function, the problem is that the function is not getting the correct id element - @id. Thanks!

Comment: Does the variable `@wagePerHour` in your script get a value?

Comment: Try passing the id when you call the GetWagePermonth on the oninput event.

Comment: @LGSon- thanks, yes i do get a value, the issue is that the value is always entering the last cell of the column because the function is getting the last@id created from the loop, instead of the current one.

Comment: @schar - how? you mean like this: <input oninput="GetWagePerMonth()" id=@id type="number" min="1" /> or in the function?

Comment: @schar, thanks! can i see then what i would do in the function, do you mean id=@id. What do i link to this?

Comment: @JaneCohen I've posted the little snippet as an answer for your to get the ID of the caller. I guess I got the question right. If not, that should be a start for you to work on it. good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input oninput="GetWagePerMonth(this)" id=@id type="number" min="1" />
```

make `<td  id=@id"></td >` into `<div  id="d"@id></div >`

and your function would access the id as

```
 function GetWagePerMonth(idx) {
    alert(idx.id); /*  */
    var wage = document.getElementById("WagePerHour").innerHTML;
    var wagePerHour = @wagePerHour;
    var wagePerMonth = wage * wagePerHour;
    wagePerMonth = round(wagePerMonth, 2).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("d"+idx.id).innerHTML = wagePerMonth;

}
```

USe this instead and see if you get any response.

```
  function GetWagePerMonth(idx) {
        alert(idx.id); /*  */
        document.getElementById("d"+idx.id).innerHTML = "Test Value";
     }
```

Hope this helps you get to a solution that you can improvise

edit:

create  a new function

```
function CallMyFunc(){
           for(i=0,i < 10, i++){
                   GetWagePerMonth(i) ;
                     }
            }
```

In the HTML part , lets see if you can create a button to call that function

```
<input type = "button" onClick="javascript:CallMyFunc()"/>
```

Comment: No, sorry nothing happened.. is this jquery because i want to use only javascript

Comment: Look at your html source after the page is rendered. Does the input element get the right id?

Comment: Yes, the alert comes up with correct id, but document.getElementById(idx.id).innerHTML = wagePerMonth; is not working

Comment: Ok couple of changes . Apparently you will have two elements with same id.. So correct that first. Call the  <td id=@id></td> as  <div id="d"@id></div> and secondly : use "d"+idx.id to get the div. See if this works

Comment: edit your question and post the latest code again. Let's see where we are.

Comment: Try to see if you can actually put some value between the divs and see if you can get to alert that content using the static  id value.

Comment: I tried var working = document.getElementById("d" + idx.id).innerHtml;
        alert(working); but alert doesnt show up

Comment: And wagePerMonth is actually returning a value? can you ensure that has a value too? I'm running out of ideas here :D

Comment: Also, use Ctrl+Shift+J in chrome to see if the script throws any errors. you can debug it here

Comment: Thanks for your patience!! wagePerMonth is returning a value in an alert, except that the function is getting an incorrect value for wagePerHour by using the first wagePerHour of the for loop, for all rows

Comment: just make this the only line in your function and see if it works... then you can figure whats wrong with the function. document.getElementById("d"+idx.id).innerHTML = "Test Val";

Comment: Yup,this is the problem, the function is not recognising the id and when i change the id of the div, it changes the text only the first time. Any ideas?

Comment: post your html source from the browser (you can obfuscate the parts you dont want to show)

Comment: I suspect your problem might be quite simple.(guessing) Your function call is oninput ..which triggers only when you change the input and only for that id. Try to see if you can use another event to trigger the events for each of the inputs.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of an event?

Comment: see the answer ... Lets see if that helps you get on the track

Comment: sorry...i've already used the first answer as shown in my edited question.Do you have any ideas?Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me!

Comment: So.what was the issue?